# Create list of case class instances

Tags: scala, loops, comparison, doobie

I have 3 vals, each of type `Array[String]`

they are all equal in length

val1.length == val2.length // true

Next, I created a case class as following:

```
case class resource(name: String, count: Int, location: String)
```

I want to create a list, a `List[resource]` such that each object of this list is created from the corresponding elements of the `val`s, i.e, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`

Something like this:

```
val newList: List[resource] = (val1(0), val2(0).toInt, val3(0)),
                              (val1(1), val2(1).toInt, val3(1)),
                              ...
                              (val1(val1.length), val2(val2.length).toInt, val3(val3.length)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Do I use flatMap, foreach, for-loops, or something else?

The idea is to create this abovementioned `newList` and compare it to the result obtained from a SQL database using doobie.

```
val comparator = sql"sql statment".query[resource]
comparator.to[List].transact(xa).unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can zip your arrays, which combines the corresponding elements of the zipped sequences into tuples, and them `map` the `resource.apply` method over the combined sequence:

```
val val1: Array[String] = Array("name 1", "name 2", "name 3")
val val2: Array[String] = Array("1", "2", "3")
val val3: Array[String] = Array("loc 1", "loc 2", "loc 3")

scala> (val1, val2.map(_.toInt), val3).zipped.map(resource)
res1: Array[resource] = Array(resource(name 1,1,loc 1), resource(name 2,2,loc 2), resource(name 3,3,loc 3))
```

You can then convert this `Array` to `List` if needed:

```
scala> (val1, val2.map(_.toInt), val3).zipped.map(resource).toList
res2: List[resource] = List(resource(name 1,1,loc 1), resource(name 2,2,loc 2), resource(name 3,3,loc 3))
```

Comment: This is a much more concise and accurate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have 3 lists such as

case class resource(name: String, count: Int, location: String)

```
val list1 = Array("s1","s2","s3")
val list2 = Array("1","2","3")
val list3 = Array("s4","s5","s6")
```

You can simply use the for loops to get the desired list of resource

```
val result = for(
  l1 <- list1;
  l2 <- list2;
  l3 <- list3
)
  yield (resource(l1,l2.toInt,l3) )
```

Note :- This code will work only if the second list contains a list of integers else we will get NumberFormatException.